# How to store a user record on another collection in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, foreign-keys

I'm trying to find how to associate a user with another collection document in Meteor and am unsure about how to do this.

My objective is to find the most efficient and future proof method for storing this information, although I am now aware this can be seen as somewhat subjective.

In my example, I am using a "Message" collection and am storing user ids on this document as both "sender" and "recipients", recipients being an array of user ids.

When I want to display information about the sender/recipients of this message, should I use helpers to output certain data? Or add things like `senderName` and `senderAvatar` onto the document itself when it gets created? Or am I missing another way of associating a user with another object that is perhaps more efficient?

Here's a JSON example:

Option 1 - Simply storing user ids on the other object (Message)

```
{
   "_id": "boDNs36xzLw7eLLhx",
   "sender": "8jpS96b4T65g5ARug",
   "recipient": "4Pa5i5vQ2gDtYQBDP",
   "message": "A new message.",
   "createdAt": "2015-10-22T21:18:18.291Z"
}
```

Option 2 - Storing more information on the document itself

```
{
  "_id": "boDNs36xzLw7eLLhx",
  "sender": "8jpS96b4T65g5ARug",
  "senderName": "Joe Bloggs",
  "senderAvatar": "http://myimg.com",
  "recipient": "4Pa5i5vQ2gDtYQBDP",
  "recipientName": "Bill Bloggs",
  "recipientAvatar": "http://myotherimg.com",
  "message": "A new message.",
  "createdAt": "2015-10-22T21:18:18.291Z"
}
```

Comment: You are asking whether or not you should denormalize your data. It's impossible to answer objectively given a two sentences long use-case. This question is very opinion-based and broad, and unfortunately not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thank you @Kyll for your comment. I'm sorry that it's opinion based but I haven't been able to find anyone making reference to their particular methods. I also confess to finding it hard to share code on SO but can provide further details if that would help.

Comment: If you want to make your question on-topic you would have to provide a sample structure (no need for actual code, JSON would do) and provide a clear set of concrete objectives (for example "retrieve all necessary data to show who sent the documents in one request").

Comment: Hi André, what do you mean by "most effective"? Can you rephrase that (and "best way") to a metric that has an objective answer? Try to avoid questions that are relative (e.g. "what's more efficient") or opinionated (e.g. "what's the best way"), as those phrases can get otherwise good questions put on hold.

Comment: Thank you both, I will try and edit the question if possible to be more objective.

Comment: No problem. Also the Help Center has a great resource on how to ask a great question to maximize your chances of getting helpful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Start here:  [MongoDB Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that link @JeremyK!

Comment: Thanks for the JSON example, and TylerH removed most opinionated parts. Now all your question needs is a clear, concrete objective (not "best performance").

Comment: Thanks Kyll, I have added an objective although am somewhat aware now thanks to @JeremeyK links that this is a recurring question in the MongoDB world!

I also found the following article helpful. http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents

Comment: Your stated objectives are very broad and subjective. "future-proof" pretty much means nothing, and it means even less in Web development. "most efficient" is hard to evaluate without a clear context, benchmarks, and profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should stick with the 1st option and then get user data from users collection by user id.

Two main arguments:

1. Second option duplicates data. If users exchange 100 messages, there are 101 "Joe Bloggs", "Bill Bloggs" etc identical strings in database.
2. If one of the users changes name, it either doesn't change in messages, or you have to update each message sent and received by this this user, which means a massive and unnecessary database load.

Comment: Many thanks KG32 I must say from everything I've been reading I do feel more at home using this method.